# excel-vba Range.Offset Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the following VBA code:

```
Set timeRange = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("DATE", MatchCase:=True) 'Cerca TIME column
 If timeRange Is Nothing Or Empty Then GoTo errorOpenColumn
 timcol = timeRange.Column
 Columns(timcol).Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
 Selection.Copy
 'Workbooks(Mainbook).Activate
 'Worksheets("Office_Data_Table").Select
 Workbooks(Mainbook).Activate
 Worksheets("Office_Data_Table").Activate
 Range("A:A").Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial 'Error aqui
 Windows(Sourcebook).Activate
```

At the time it executes it will give an error in line `Range("A:A").Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial`, but would not give an error (*No valid entry. Application will be closed*); but if I apply the `Offset(0,6)` it will work.

Obviously my problem is that I want to apply the `Offset (6,0)`, and not the other one :-).

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 2):

`Range("A:A")` selects the whole column - and `OFFSET(6,0)` tries to offset the whole column down - which is not possible as it's already completely selected! Instead, you might want to use `Range("A1"). Offset(6,0)` or `Range("A7")` directly.